# XML sitemap in Multilingual site

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, xml-sitemap

How to configure xml sitemap for multi language site.For translation I am using [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module and for [xml sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap). Now there are only one link show in NL site map and 26 in default language.[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating cached files with Update button? And are you sure, that all Dutch content is included to XML sitemap (can by set in content types settings, bud also in nodes directly - so maybe English nodes are included and Ducht are not).

Comment: Yes I checked all this.

Comment: "Add new XML sitemap" for each language.

Answer (score 0):

Run the cron manually it will update this.If you have more translations for NL it will get update there.

cheers!